# How to change default search engine with javascript on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set the default search engine of a chrome to my website when the user clicks a button. Is it possible to do this with javascript? If it is possible, how do I accomplish this? Thank You.

Comment: You can't set the default search engine - the user has to do that.

Comment: I doubt this is possible since the default search engine is a Windows setting

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski No it's not.  I set my default search engine within Chrome, not Windows.  Maybe the Windows setting (I didn't know it existed!) is for Internet Explorer only.

Comment: @Archer When you try to set your default search engine from the search engine itself, it just redirects you to the Windows Settings app.

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski I don't set a default search engine from a search engine.  Chrome is my browser and that browser is where I set the default search engine *that is used by that browser*.  It has nothing to do with Windows.

Comment: @Archer OMG haha I just realized I read the question wrong. You're right...it's too early for this ;)

Comment: I have think is more simple to add a button, and I've always thought on the internet is everything possible, I hope to find a solution. would really help me a lot. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski Have some coffee.  Wake up!  :D

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sidebar/Adding_search_engines_from_Web_pages) might be helpful for FF. For Chrome you'll find it [here](http://2ality.com/2013/06/chrome-omnibox-search.html). Chrome automatically adds it to "other search engines" if you set your meta correctly (conforming the OpenSearch format). As pointed out above: you provide the search, user has to opt-in for it in their browser.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mr.@AndreiGheorghiu

Answer (score 0):

You cannot currently change default search engine with Javascript. JS does not provide any methods to do so. 
The best you can do is make an non interuptive alert to remind the user to make the switch.

Also websites like Bing make you install a program to make it the default search engine on chrome and firefox. That is also an option.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Or another option is changing search provider by extension.

doc: https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override

key: search_provider